# Port forwarding is not working (Linksys WRT54G)

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding

I have enabled port 3000 for my router in Applications and Gaming, but for some reason it will not work. When I try to access the port with my ip in the browser (http://xx.xx.x.x:3000/) it says, 'This webpage is not available' immediately. But if I enter an ip that has not been forwarded in the browser, the loading sign just keeps spinning so it seems as though the port has been forwarded correctly but something is stopping it. I recently transferred to a new Comcast account and this was working before, so I'm not what happened.

Comment: Are you trying to access it from within or outside of your network? If outside the network are you using the same modem and/or router? You said you transfered to a new Comcast account, does that mean you were on Comcast before?

Comment: I've tried accessing it from within and outside the network (from my phone). Yea, I was on Comcast before and we got a new Comcast account  using the same modem and router.

Comment: If your not able to access it from within the network that makes me believe the culprit is the server. Have you tried a loopback test on the port?

Comment: I'm not sure how to run a loopback test. I'm on mac osx 10.8.5. I ran the following: traceroute -p 3000 -v xx.xx.x.x (my ip) and got: 2  c-xx.xx.x.x.hsd1.wa.comcast.net (xx.xx.x.x) 36 bytes to 192.168.1.102  2.826 ms  3.626 ms  17.343 ms. The other thing is that I've tried it from two different macs, changing the port forwarding each time and still no go. Also, I ran this port scanner: http://www.whatsmyip.org/port-scanner/ and it says the port is closed. Shouldn't enabling the port range in the router config (http://192.168.1.1/Forward.htm) open it up?

Comment: A loopback test is simply testing 127.0.0.1:port. In this case 127.0.0.1:3000 to see if you get a response and yes it should open the port but maybe it doesn't know where to forward the port. If its set to forward the port correctly and the server is running then I'm at a loss sorry